# Usar forEach e useState de forma sequêncial

Tags: react, foreach, fetch

Estou tentando fazer um dashboard com o número de alunos e posições dos mesmos em uma escolinha de futebol. Meu objetivo é que apareça um card para cada posição e o número de alunos na posição seja incrementado de acordo com as informações do banco de dados, ficando assim: [image: Dashboard contendo o número de alunos cadastrados e as posições na escolas]

Porém, ao invés de agrupar os card e incrementar a quantidade, os cards de repetem no primeiro render e só nos próximos eles começam a agrupar, ficando assim:
[image: Dashboard com os cards repetidos ao invés de agrupados.]

O bd ainda não foi implementado, então estou usando o json-server e faço um fetch dentro de um useEffect. Informações do bd.json:

```
{
  "alunos": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nome": "João",
      "posicao_campo": "7",
      "posicao_futsal": "5"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nome": "José",
      "posicao_campo": "7",
      "posicao_futsal": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "nome": "Marcos",
      "posicao_campo": "3",
      "posicao_futsal": "4"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "nome": "Juan",
      "posicao_campo": "4",
      "posicao_futsal": "4"
    }
  ]
```

Ao fazer o fetch, chamo a seguinte função:

```
const conferePosicaoAluno = (alunos) => {
  alunos.forEach((aluno) => {
  //Confere a posição no campo
    switch (aluno.posicao_campo) {
      case '1':
        addPosicaoCampo('Goleiro');
        break;
      case '2':
        addPosicaoCampo('Zagueiro');
        break;
      case '3':
        addPosicaoCampo('Lateral Direita');
        break;
      case '4':
        addPosicaoCampo('Lateral Esquerda');
        break;
      case '5':
        addPosicaoCampo('Meia');
        break;
      case '6':
        addPosicaoCampo('Volante');
        break;
      case '7':
        addPosicaoCampo('Atacante');
        break;
    }
    // Confere a posição no futsal
    switch (aluno.posicao_futsal) {
      case '1':
        addPosicaoFutsal('Goleiro');
        break;
      case '2':
        addPosicaoFutsal('Fixo');
        break;
      case '3':
        addPosicaoFutsal('Ala Direita');
        break;
      case '4':
        addPosicaoFutsal('Ala Esquerda');
        break;
      case '5':
        addPosicaoFutsal('Pivô');
        break;
      }
    });
  };
```

Na parte do front, estou usando React.js com chakra-ui.

Variáveis:

```
const [alunos, setAlunos] = useState('');
const [posicoesCampo, setPosicoesCampo] = useState([]);
const [posicoesFutsal, setPosicoesFutsal] = useState([]);
```

Funções para manipular as informações dos cards:

```
const addPosicaoCampo = (type) => {
  // Verifica se a posição já foi cadastrada no array de posições de campo
  let item = posicoesCampo.find((item) => {
    return item.type == type;
  });

  if (item) {
    // Caso a posição já exista, adiciona 1 ao valor
    let itemIndex = posicoesCampo.indexOf(item);
    posicoesCampo[itemIndex].value += 1;
    setPosicoesCampo(posicoesCampo);

  } else {
    // Se não, adiciona uma nova posição com o valor 1
    setPosicoesCampo((prevPosicoesCampo) => [...prevPosicoesCampo, { type, value: 1 }]);
  }
};

const addPosicaoFutsal = (type) => {
  // Verifica se a posição já foi cadastrada no array de posições de futsal
  let item = posicoesFutsal.find((item) => {
  return item.type == type;
    });

  if (item) {
    // Caso a posição já exista, adiciona 1 ao valor
    let itemIndex = posicoesFutsal.indexOf(item);
    posicoesFutsal[itemIndex].value += 1;
    setPosicoesFutsal(posicoesFutsal);
      
  } else {
    // Se não, adiciona uma nova posição com o valor 1
    setPosicoesFutsal((prevPosicoesFutsal) => [...prevPosicoesFutsal, { type, value: 1 }]);
  }
};
```

Código de renderização:

```
return (
  <>
    <Card icon={FaGraduationCap} title="Alunos Cadastrados" content={alunos.length} />

    {posicoesCampo.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={i}
          icon={FaFutbol}
          title={`${item.position} (Campo)`}
          content={item.amount}
        />
      );
    })}

    {posicoesFutsal.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={i}
          icon={FaRegFutbol}
          title={`${item.position} (Futsal)`}
          content={item.amount}
        />
      );
    })}
  </>
);
```

O component Card é apenas para organizar as informações e estilizar elas.

Estou há alguns dias tentando descobrir o motivo, já tentei realizar esse procedimento com um for...of assíncrono, mas também não deu certo. Caso possam ajudar, ficarei muito grato!

Comment: Já que o cenário é futebol e as posições já são determinadas, recomendo (para facilitar sua lógica) já deixar um array de objetos contendo os atributos `type` e `value` e iterar a lista específica, daria até para deixar agrupar dentro de cada objeto da lista um array contendo os jogadores. Essa simples mudança já deixaria seu código mais limpo e simples. Exemplo: `[{nome: 'Atacante', id: '7', qtd: 0, jogadores: []}]`
Se possível coloque o código da renderização também

Comment: @FelippeTadeu acho que eu entendi. Vou tentar implementar aqui e se der certo, aviso!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseado no comentário do @FelipeTadeu consegui desenvolver uma solução para meu problema.

Criei um objeto chamado *positions*, o qual dividi em 2 arrays e atribuí as posições de cada modalidade:

```
const positions: {
  campo: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Goleiro',
    qtd: 0,
  }
...
],
  futsal: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Goleiro',
    qtd: 0,        
  }
...
]
```

Modifiquei por completo as funções addPositionCampo e addPositionFutsal, deixando-as mais simples também:

```
const addPositionCampo = (positionId) => {
  positions.campo[positionId - 1].qtd += 1;
  setPosicoesCampo(positions.campo);
};

const addPositionFutsal = (positionId) => {
  positions.futsal[positionId - 1].qtd += 1;
  setPosicoesFutsal(positions.futsal);
};
```

Como sei que o index da posição é sempre o id - 1, não me importei de deixar desta maneira.

No fetch, atribuí o resultado à variável alunos e rodei o forEach nela, chamando as funções addPositionCampo e addPositionFutsal:

```
useEffect(() => {
  alunos.forEach((aluno) => {
    addPositionCampo(aluno.posicao_campo);
    addPositionFutsal(aluno.posicao_futsal);
  });
}, [alunos]);
```

Por fim, mudei também a renderização, a qual ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
return (
  <>
    <Card icon={FaGraduationCap} title="Alunos Cadastrados" content={alunos.length} />

    {posicoesCampo.map(
      (item) =>
        item.qtd > 0 && (
          <Card
            key={item.id}
            icon={FaFutbol}
            title={`${item.name} (Campo)`}
            content={item.qtd}
          />
        )
    )}

    {posicoesFutsal.map(
      (item) =>
        item.qtd > 0 && (
          <Card
            key={item.id}
            icon={FaRegFutbol}
            title={`${item.name} (Futsal)`}
            content={item.qtd}
          />
        )
    )}
  </>
);
```

Consegui alcançar o objetivo, mostrando apenas 1 card por posição e incrementando o valor.

Resultado obtido:
[image: Resultado obtido]